# SQL copy data to new table adding sequences by data grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am stuck on SQL I need to write (and I'm a SQL novice).

I have a table that contains data with a structure like this:

Table: CURRENT_TABLE

| item_id | col1 | col2 | other_col |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | A | B | C |
| 200 | D | E | F |
| 200 | G | H | I |
| 300 | J | K | L |
| 200 | M | N | O |

And the primary key is:  item_id, col1 and col2.

But this PK structure needs to change.  What I need to do is copy the data to a new table and add a sequence that is only for the item_id.  So the result will be:

Table: NEW_TABLE

| item_id | seq | col1 | col2 | other_col |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 0 | A | B | C |
| 200 | 0 | D | E | F |
| 200 | 1 | G | H | I |
| 200 | 2 | M | N | O |
| 300 | 0 | J | K | L |

In the case the key will be:  item_id and seq.

I am currently doing this in SQL Server, but please try to keep the solution as close to ANSI SQL as possible because I will eventually need Oracle and PostgreSQL versions, too, for our clients that use those.  But to be clear, my immediate concern is SQL Server.

I'm fine using CTEs, I just can't think of how to do this right now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select item_id,
       row_number() over (partition by item_id order by (select null)) - 1 as seq,
       col1, col2, other_col
from t;
```

You can use `into` to put the results in a new table.